# How to style widget with post count different than without post count

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a border below my li elements in the wordpress widget types that would be appropriate. The a element inside is then set to block so that it gives them a nice easy to click full width.

The problem, when you choose the option "show post count" when adding a widget such as categories or archives it displays the post count as plain text after the a tag and because the a tag is block it pushes the post number text to the line below.

Whether you choose to show post count or not show post count it still gives you the exact same element identifyer for example "widget_categories".  So how do I style the post count so its not on the next line but still keep the links for the non post count list items full width?

Here's an example on the sidebar
www.bbmthemes.com/themes/modular/blog-standard/

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem you will need to remove the

```
display:block;
```

for the `ul.widgets ul a` and add in it's place

```
line-height: 33px;
```

What you are going to achieve with this is to have the same visual effect.

What you are going to lose by doing this is your links are going to work only on the text and not on the "box".

The other way out of this is to find where this post count is coming from and make some changes to this. For example change the text count to be inside a `<span class="post_count">` so you can apply some css formatting on that class in order to fix your problem properly.

Hope this helps